# Yii2 extend console MessageController

Tags: php, console, yii2

I have some functionality, that I want to add to `yii\console\controllers\MessageController::actionExtract()`.

So normally what I have done - extended yii controller with my own controller and placed it to `app\commands` directory.

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;

class MessageController extends \yii\console\controllers\MessageController{ /* .. */ }
```

For test purposes I added method named `actionTest`.

When I do `> yii` command, all I get is

[image]

Now I copy-pasted exactly same controller and just renamed it to `MsgController`. Previous controller left intact.

So now `> yii` gives me

[image]

---

> **yii message/test** - 'Unknown command message/test'
>
> **yii msg/test** - 'OK'

---

My app\config\console.php has `'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands'`

How should I properly extend MessageController and continue use standard yii command (means not changing controller name to have new command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the controller like you did and in console configuration add:

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'message' => 'app\commands\MessageController',
],
```

Comment: Can you explain when do we need to use `controllerMap` and why Yii does not *see* my extended class with same name?

Comment: Console application by default [enables](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.11.2/framework/console/Application.php#L76) core commands and [maps](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.11.2/framework/console/Application.php#L128) them in `$controllerMap`. When you add your controller with the same name it is overriden in map list so you need to over-override it back (or switch `$enableCoreCommands` in console\Application off).